Am I able to withdraw a graduate application?
What happened was that i accidentally sent an application for admission for a graduate course for a college in the US and i live in the UK. I sent an email to admissions to withdraw my application but I’ve been panicking cause I don’t even go to university in the UK.

Why panic? What bad thing is going to possibly happen based on this?

I assume you "applied" to a real university, and not to a diploma mill.
Nothing will happen to you. I assume that you applied electronically. As an application asks the applicant to upload additional information (such as transcripts and letters of reference), your application is and will stay incomplete and not be considered. In addition, you have to pay an application fee, which I presume you did not. You might get at the most an automatic remainder letter that your application is incomplete. It is possible that the admissions center has manually deleted your application upon receipt of your email, but equally possible that they did not do anything as there is no real need.
In all, you have a started application that has been abandoned. Even if you would have completed an application, you do not have to accept the offer of admission.
(If you would have applied to a "diploma mill", they might try to harass you into paying fees, but much more likely, they will not do anything because this is not their business model. They make money from selling fake degrees via fake courses. In any case, just do not pay. It is also possible that you were about to fall for a scam. They will then try to put you in an emotionally unbalanced state, for example by installing fear. In this case, you just have to break off contact. Given that you are "panicking", this might be the case.)
